# Lag function in SAS for checking previous value

Tags: sas

In SAS, I would like to create a label that check the previous sell indicator: if the sell indicator of the previous time period is 1/0 and in the current is 0/1 (meaning that it has changed) then I assign a value 1 to the ind variable.

The dataset looks like:

```
Customer  Time Sell_Ind
1          2      1
1          3      0
1          4      0
2          23     0
2          24     0
2          30     0
5          12     1
5          11     0
```

And so on.

My expected output would be

```
Customer  Time Sell_Ind   Ind 
    1          2      1    0
    1          3      0    1
    1          4      0    0
    2          23     0    0
    2          24     0    0
    2          30     0    0
    5          12     1    0
    5          11     0    1
```

The previous/current check is meant by customer.

I have tried as follows

```
data mydata;
set original;
By customer;
Lag_sell_ind=lag(sell_ind);
If first.customer then Lag_sell_ind=.;
Run;
```

But it does not return the expected output.
In sql I would probably use partition by customer over time but I do not know how to do the same in SAS.

Comment: I think change `If first.customer then Lag_sell_ind=.;` to `If first.customer then Lag_sell_ind=0;` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this using the IFN Function like below.

```
data have;
input Customer Time Sell_Ind;
datalines;
1 2  1
1 3  0
1 4  0
2 23 0
2 24 0
2 30 0
5 12 1
5 11 0
;

data want;
   set have;
   by customer;  
   Lag_sell_ind = ifn(first.customer, 0, lag(sell_ind));
Run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You were halfway through, you only need to add one if statement to achieve the desired output.

```
data want;
set have;
by customer;
lag=lag(sell_ind);
if first.customer then lag=.;
if sell_ind ne lag and lag ne . then ind = 1;
else ind = 0;
drop lag;
run;
```